# kvm-linux with zero(thin) client

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualization, linux-kvm, thin-client

I have to run a virtualization in my office. Can I use kvm-linux virtualization with zero(thin) client?

I know vmware supports zero client protocols well but does kvm support it too and I can connect to  the kvm container with zero client in a private network?

Also, what is your idea about kvm-linux for my usage; are there any  better options?

At this time I used vmware trial and its really good but I have to try some open source solutions too!